# Modeling multiple levels of inheritance using discriminated unions

Tags: f#

Is there a recommended way to model multiple levels of inheritance in F#, presumably using a discriminated union?

Taking something like the following in C#:

```
class Expr { }
class SourceExpr : Expr { }
class JoinExpr : SourceExpr { }
class TableExpr : SourceExpr { }
```

I've done this in F#:

```
type SourceExpr =
    | Join of JoinExpr
    | Table of TableExpr

type Expr = 
    | Source of SourceExpr
    | ...
```

Is there a better way? Does this provide the same polymorphic behavior as inheritance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to be too prescriptive here without more information.  Depending on what you are trying to do, it may make more sense to use a class hierarchy or a discriminated union (DU).  The most common/obvous trade-offs are that class hierarchies are 'open' whereas DUs are 'closed'.  That is, you can easily add new types to a class hierarchy, but adding a new operation (abstract method on base class) requires changing all existing classes.  In contrast, with DUs you can easily add a new operation (function that pattern matches over the data type), but to add a new case (subclass) you have to redefine the type and update all the existing operations to deal with the new case.  (This is sometimes called "the expression problem".)

A typical example that's good for DUs is a compiler; you have a language abstract syntax tree where the language and tree structure are fixed, but you may author many different tree transform operations inside the compiler.  A typical example that's good for class hierarchies is UI frameworks; you have some base class(es) that defines all the operations that widgets must supply (Draw, Resize, ...) but then users will add their own custom subtypes with extra capabilities.

Comment: I'm working on a parser, so I think DUs are the right choice. But there are expressions which seem to inherit from others. There are functions that should accept a Join or Table, which are both Sources. There are also functions that should accept an Expr, of which Source is one of the many options. I can't help but think of it in OO terms, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to model this relatively static hierarchy while maintaining the same type of polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Modeling it with types will work well. If you have two types that are "also" the same thing, add a new type that discriminates between them and use that. The only downside is that you will have to do more deconstruction, but pattern matching and active patterns where you need 'em makes that pretty tolerable. I'm doing this with some fairly complicated recursive types and an FParsec parser and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

you can model the classes using inheritance in F# just as you do in C#....OR...you can model the requirements using discriminated unions as you show.

No, discriminated unions do not allow the same sort of polymorphic behaviour, in particular you will potentially have to amend all you pattern matches if you add new cases.

It has it's advantages though, I tend to write code with discriminated unions in F#, and inheritance in C#...UNLESS....I have a specific concern about extensibility.

you aren't modelling any levels of inheritance using discrimated unions...you are comparing apples with carrots.

you can model the same requirements in both paradigms...I'd go discriminated union in your context....I think it will make the code simpler to read....but that's subjective.